# WIQL "not contains words" returns false positives

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, tfs, wiql

I am running a WIQL query that contains this:

```
"And [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria] Not Contains Words '*Given*When*Then*'";
```

I would expect this to not return any AcceptanceCriteria that contain the string "Given" followed by "When" followed by "Then". However I am receiving this item in the results:

```
"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria":"<div></div><div><b>Given</b></div><div>Frontier has to submit the replenishment order creation request to Maestro</div><div><b>When</b></div><div>Prophet sends the replenishment order recommendation via REPLENORD feed</div><div><b>Then</b></div><div>Frontier should be able to determine and remove the logic to include the PLANNER_ID&nbsp;/ SCS_ID as mandatory information needed for replenishment order creation</div>"
```

Am I using this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the query operators **`Contains Words`** or **`Does Not Contain Words`** to search with the wildcard character (**`*`**), you can only use the wildcard character at the end of a partial word or phrase.

In your case, the expression you set (**`*Given*When*Then*`**) obviously does not obey this restriction. So, it is a wrong expression.

For more details, you can see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-operators-variables?view=azure-devops#full-text-and-partial-word-searches).